# ng-animate : conditionally switching "back" transition (BUG?)

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-animate

**Hi everyone,**

reading through [this google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/GzsaiWIGy-I) and the fiddles and blogpost linked from there, I managed to get page transitions working with ng-animate.

**Here's [my Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/robro/Xck5Z/)**

```
the fiddle is nicely commented, please let me know if anything's unclear
```

By setting a 'transitionClass' (either .LR or .RL) on the ng-view I was able to trigger different css-transitions for every view change.

Now, what I want to do, is manually applying a "back" transition in case of changing the view one step back, no matter whether that step back is caused by a link within the app or the browser's back button.

To do so, within app.run(), I'm listening for $locationChangeStart, saving the current url slug and then checking against it on the next $locationChangeStart to determine whether we're going back one page. If that's the case, the "back" transition is applied.

**This works pretty well, except for...**

The entering page (.page-enter, .page-enter-active) is transitioning as expected, while the leaving page (.page-leave, .page-leave-active) seems to be stuck on the previously used transition.

I'd expect, setting a transitionClass 'LR' on the ng-view, that both pages, entering and leaving, use the css transition for '.LR page-enter' and 'LR page-leave'.

What seems to happen instead: If the transitionClass was 'ANY' before, the ng-animate will use '.LR page-enter' for the entering page and '.ANY page-leave' for the leaving page.

**Reproducing the 'bug':**

App starts on Page 1. Go from 1 to 2. Now go from 2 to 3, this transition is broken. Go from 3 to 1, this transition works as expected. *Both transitions are 'RL' (Right To Left), so they should look the same.* The only difference being that page 2 enters 'LR' while page 3 enters 'RL'. So, actually, page 1 will use the '.enter-active' transition that was originally set for page 3 when changing from 2 to 3.

**Is this the expected behavior?**

I'm majorly confuzzled right now, but only working with angular for the last week or so and ng-animate being relatively new feature I might very well be missing something. So before reporting a bug or anything I'd welcome any input on this.

**Thanks!**

Comment: I did try going through your code but it got a little too crazy for my patience! In any case, you'd be far better off implementing conditional transitions like this using javascript. Take a look at
http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.directive:ngAnimate
and scroll down to javascript-defined animations.

Comment: @IanHaggerty, thanks for getting back to me. I was under the impression, that only css transitions are hardware accelerated. That's why I favored using css- over js-transitions. I'll see whether I can condense the fiddle tomorrow and make the the transition issue more apparent.

Comment: You could still use CSS transitions from js, just add a class and set a time-out to remove the class (that is how the implementation works in the first place - it just goes one step further by inspecting your css and finding the right time to time-out). Setting up handlers on $locationChangeStart feels very very wrong for some simple animations, think about scalability. That is a site-wide handler your registering. Every route will invoke it. Sure you could limit it to local scope, but even then presentation logic is in wrong place ... etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so based on the comments I'm pretty sure you want the incoming page to also determine exit animations to apply to the outgoing page. So you really need your $locationChange code.

It also looks like the problem you are seeing is that you are setting a class on the parent independently on the incoming page but there is nothing to keep the animations waiting for this class change to occur.

The simplest fix seems to be to make the ng-animate depend on your changing variable to determine the animation class names:

```
<ng-view ng-animate="transitionClass"></ng-view>
```

then the CSS selectors just collapse into single classes:

```
.LR-enter-active {
  ...
}
```

(where transitionClass is still being set on the $rootScope in the locationChangeStart:)

```
 $rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
 ...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9XPVX/4/

Comment: It looks like the transitionClass doesn't effectively get propagated to the class until the transition is over, hence what you see is whatever the rule was for the page you are on: http://jsfiddle.net/9XPVX/

Comment: So here is a hack to put the transform in directly at the rootElement of the app: http://jsfiddle.net/9XPVX/2/ (the /1/ version shows pulling the old setting on locationChangeSuccess to make sure we are getting the new animation or nothing.)

Comment: Wow, thanks! This works exactly as expected. I can see how `$rootElement.attr("data-transform", $rootScope.transitionClass);` and `*[data-transform=RL] .page-enter {…}` make this work. Searching a deeper understanding I tried to use `ng-class` directly on the body element (which is the $rootElement), but it refused to work again. But `$rootElement.attr("class", $rootScope.transitionClass);` and changing the CSS back to `.RL` instead of `*[data-transform=LR]` works! So using a class doesn't seem to be the problem, but binding that class via ng-class is? See jsfiddle.net/robro/wh9ZR/2/

Comment: Your last edit (that links to http://jsfiddle.net/9XPVX/4/) makes things even more clear. I'm not quite sure, why a class selector like `.RL-enter` works but `.RL .page-enter` doesn't, but for now I'm more than happy that it works at all. Solved & Accepted. Thank you so much!

Comment: Sure, I am glad it works for you! I think it's really that the ng-class gets its response to the value change on to the run queue but there is nothing to indicate the current sequence needs to wait for it to complete its DOM update.