# Angularjs Prev and Next sliding animation

Tags: angularjs

I am making an Angular app with previous and next buttons. I want the ng-view to animate different directions depending on which button the user clicks (prev or next). I have a working example that animates the view properly for the next button. How do I make it work for the prev button?

http://plnkr.co/edit/3dEX35iAg6EQr1IiYGqo?p=preview

If I change the css from this:

```
  .view-animate.ng-enter {
    left:100%;
  }
  .view-animate.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
    left:0;
  }
  .view-animate.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
    left:-100%;
  }
```

to this:

```
  .view-animate.ng-enter {
    left:-100%;
  }
  .view-animate.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
    left:0;
  }
  .view-animate.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
    left:100%;
  }
```

Then the animation reverses quite nicely. But how do I do this dynamically base on wether the user presses the prev or next button?

Comment: man check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/17898548/158421